# Xceed Tokenized textbox search "starts with"

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

Xceed WPF Toolkit Tokenized textbox searches items text "**contains**" by default

I am using Xceed WPF Toolkit Tokenized textbox and it searches text in the items using "contains". How can we search the text "**Starts with**"?